# Why does long long in c++ does not hold 2500^3

Tags: c++, long-integer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    long long a=2501*2501*2501;
    cout<<a;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried unsigned long long too and all the time it gives some gibberish answer.
I checked the capacity of long long and it can hold this value.

Comment: 2501 is int, not long long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `long long` can definitely hold this value. The problem is that the expression that you are using to compute it, i.e. `2501*2501*2501`, is an `int` expression. The compiler computes the result using integers. This causes an overflow, because the result does not fit in 32 bits. Hence the result becomes invalid before the compiler knows that the value goes into a `long long` variable.

Add `LL` suffix to one of the numbers to fix the problem:

```
long long a=2501LL*2501*2501;
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/RhFmv2)

Comment: 32 bits is a typical size for `int`, but the standard only guarantees that it's at least 16.  For that matter, `int` *could* be 64 bits.

Comment: Is there any reason not to put `LL` on the end of every integer literal? I wish that integer literals were 'typeless'

Comment: @KeithThompson Right, 32 was only my guess, knowing that something wrong is happening. The chances of hitting a non-embedded C compiler with `int` size of less than 32 bits are small these days, so I took my chance here.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Readability would be one such reason. Generally, though, the compiler should issue a warning about the overflow (and it's a good idea to treat all warnings as errors).